# How to load raw csv file on my laptop in S3 bucket in URL https://s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/snowflake-essentials

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Am taking up course for Snowflake and need to load data .csv file in S3 bucket mentioned https://s3.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/snowflake-essentials.

Please suggest how this could be done ,Do i need a AWS account and buy space in S3 ?

Answer (score 3):

You no need of AWS account, you already have mentioned S3 bucket so just create external stage and then execute copy command to load your data into final target table.